# Countif with 2 ranges, 1 range of data can be variable but contain duplications

Tags: excel, range, unique, countif, sumproduct

I'm trying to perform a count based on this data table, column 3 is the column i'm trying to automate. What i want it to do is count how many unique products each person made. I'm not sure if i'm overcomplicating but every solution i try doesn't work - i played around with sumproduct but couldn't get it to work.

The problem is the item made by column contains a static list of names, but in theory the product could contain anything.

What formula would work in the "unique products made by person" column please?

Any help appreciated.

[image: Data]

Comment: You can use UNIQUE and FILTER formula if you have 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex,

Here's the formula:

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER($E$2:$E$10,$D$2:$D$10=$A2))),0)
```

Note: Refers to the setup below.
[image]

HTH

Comment: Amazing thank you - UNIQUE is completely new to me

Comment: Alex, it's tough to keep up as they keep adding new functions and changing old ones, e.g.   Vlookup & HLookup being replaced by XLookup although the previous 2 still exist.